# How to use a Scala sub-class constructor for a member within the super-class?

Tags: scala, constructor, superclass

I want to invoke the constructor of the sub-class from the super-class (`Tree[A]`) to create additional instances of the sub-class of type `A` (`Part` or `Project`). It seems there must be a way that is better than the mess of creating the intermediate method `newChild` since things like `List` work. I have heard the maybe CanBuildFrom may address this problem.

Extract from working code:

```
abstract class Tree[A](parent: Option[A], key: Int) {
  protected def newChild(aKey: Int): A
  lazy val children: List[A] = childrenOf.map(newChild(_))
  ...
  }

case class Part(parent: Option[Part], key: Int) extends Tree[Part](parent, key) {
  protected def newChild(aKey: Int) = Part(Some(this), aKey)
  ...
  }

case class Project(parent: Option[Project], key: Int) extends Tree[Project](parent, key) {
  protected def newChild(aKey: Int) = Project(Some(this), aKey)
  ...
  }
...
"*" #> <ul>{Part(None, pKey).expandAsHtml}</ul>
```

What is a better way to use a Scala sub-class constructor for a member within the super-class?

Comment: Shouldn't you be inverting that logic and invoking the superclass constructor from the subclass constructor?  It's the subclass that knows what order to do things in, not the superclass.

Comment: I'm confused. Does this code compile or not? If it compiles, what code does not compile? And what is the error message (full error message, including line of code and column indicator)?

Comment: @DCS added "Extract from working code" note.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at it backwards.  When an object is created, its constructor is called; this delegates to its superclass's constructor either by default or by explicit invocation.  You *can't* call the subclass's constructor from the superclass's constructor, because it's the subclass's constructor that called the superclass's constructor in the first place.

You need to look at your logic and remember that the way a subclass is known is that *it* is being directly instantiated; it's not that the superclass is being instantiated with the subclass as some kind of parameter, instead the superclass is instantiated as a step in instantiating the subclass, and the superclass should only know about its own structure, leaving subclass details to the subclass constructor that triggered the superclass.

Comment: I believe the super-class's (`Tree`) constructor is invoked in the extend line. Then the value for `children` instantiates new different instances of the sub-class (either a `Project` or a `Part`). `newChild` was fabricated to make this work which it does but it requires the sub-classes to each implement it. It seems like there should be a way to invoke the constructor for another instance of the sub-class.  

Is your answer meaning that it cannot be done or that it should not be done?

Comment: Not exactly; `extend` tells it to add to all subclass constructors an invocation of the superclass constructor, if one isn't already there.  Are you saying that on construction of a particular subclass instance you want to trigger creation of another similar/sibling instance?  In any case, this still belongs in the subclass, not the superclass.

Comment: Each instance has a `val children` of type `List[A]`. Each of the instances in the list again contain a `children` list ... The intent of the super-class is to remove the details of the implementation of the tree (as a `List[A]`) from the sub-class to a common place in the super-class.

Comment: OK, I am at a loss; parents simply do not normally inherit from children, and I am not sure how to get this across.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try one more:  Can you force the superclass to invoke the subclass constructor somehow?  Almost certainly.  Can you force Scala to run the inheritance tree backwards so that the superclass constructor is invoked initially instead of the subclass constructor?  *No.*  The first thing a constructor does is run its superclass constructor.  (See http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-for-java-refugees-part-3 starting at "Often times when you override a method...".)  You can't turn this off or turn it backwards; the subclass always invokes the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the only way to achieve this is by using reflection.

I found a tutorial here: http://www.heimetli.ch/java/create-new-instance.html

This way you can get the constructor of the subclass within your superclass and call it to create a new instance of your subclass.

However you somehow would have to make sure that your subclasses implement  constructors with a specific argument list.